# Set No default Tab selected in Tablayout. (Unselect all Tab Items)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

My Tablayout has Categories as TabItems and by default, my activity shows all the data. The problem is when i open my activity the **First TabItem is selected by Default**. I want **all the tabs to be unselected** when the Activity loads and should only be selected by user interaction.[The Four TabItems and The first one is selected by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyLZt.png)